# Obj-C factory method not exposed to Swift subclasses

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, swift, nsimage

More specifically imageNamed does not get exposed to Swift subclasses of NSImage even when all other convenience inits are inherited.

According to Apple's docs Objective-C factory methods "get mapped as convenience initializers in Swift."

Consequently the NSImage factory method

`+ (NSImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name`

gets mapped to Swift's

`NSImage(named: "anything")`

Also, in the Swift Programming Language book we see that the rules for subclass initializer inheritance are:

“Rule 1
If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

Rule 2
If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.”

It thus follows that the subclass

`class T : NSImage {
}`

would inherit all the superclass' initializers, both designated and convenience, yet the following will not work

`let I = T(named: "anything")`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that seems to be that the `named:` initializer has a return type of `NSImage`

```
class NSImage : NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding, NSPasteboardReading, NSObjectProtocol, NSPasteboardWriting {

    /*All instance variables are private*/

    init?(named name: String) -> NSImage /* If this finds & creates the image, only name is saved when archived */
```

while other (not all) initializers have no return type

```
    init(size aSize: NSSize)
    init?(data: NSData) /* When archived, saves contents */
    init?(contentsOfFile fileName: String) /* When archived, saves contents */
    init?(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) /* When archived, saves contents */
    init?(byReferencingFile fileName: String) /* When archived, saves fileName */
    init(byReferencingURL url: NSURL) /* When archived, saves url, supports progressive loading */
```

Now because of that, if you have a class `T` that is a subclass of `NSImage` you would expect `T(named:)` to return an instance of `T` but if you do not provide your own implementation, the superclass implementation would be called and as we can see in the declaration, it returns an `NSImage`.

Why is it different than all other initializers? I don't know.
Perhaps the underlying implementation and caching mechanisms that `NSImage` uses lead to this inconsistency. But what's more important is that the `+[NSImage imageNamed:]` does not call any of the `NSImage` designated initializers.

Have a look at this example I cooked up witg Cocoa Touch's `UIImage`: https://gist.github.com/bartekchlebek/d61154add8525218ae3a

You can see there, that I create a subclass of `UIImage` called `MyImage` and I override all `UIImage`'s initializers, place `NSLog`s in them and return nil.

In

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I call `-[MyImage imageNamed:]` and notice, that none of the `NSLog`'s placed in the designated initializers are printed. I also print the class of the instance created with `-[MyImage imageNamed:]` and you can see that it is not `MyImage` but `UIImage` (putting aside the fact that I return `nil` in all initializers ;) )

---

In conclusion, `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` does not call any of the `UIImage`'s designated initializers, thus overriding them will not make `+[MyImage imageNamed:]` return an instance of `MyImage`. And I expect `NSImage` to behave the same way.

This subtlety causes `Swift` not to inherit the `named:` initializer, because swift **requires** convenience initializers to go through a designated initializer, while Objective-C did not require that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Whilst I agree with your observations it is still not clear to me that this isn't either just a bug in the conversion of the convenience init or an omission from the documentation.

Comment: @TeoSartori it appears that only convenience constructors with `instancetype` return type are taken under consideration by Swift when it comes to subclasses. I'll update my answer in a couple of hours with some further observations I had, and would like to hear what you think about that. So far it appears to me that it's an omission in the docs.